# Some problem in mongo update when the $in with upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The code:

```
      let newArray = ['test','when','mongo'];
      db.collection('test').update(
        { keyword: { $in: newArray } },
        { $inc: { search_num: 1 } },
        {
            upsert: true,
            multi: true,
        })
```

i want to upsert like :

```
{keyword:"test",search_num:1},
{keyword:"when",search_num:1},
{keyword:"mongo",search_num:1}
```

but it only insert :

```
{search_num:1}
```

How can I insert the keyword foreach in the $in query array?

Comment: try using `updateMany` instead

Comment: You can't get the behaviour you're looking for, the best you can do is split this into 3 updateOne operations

Comment: @Ashwyn Horton How

Answer (score 0):

Just a small work around, you can try this

```
 let newArray = ['test','when','mongo'];

 newArray.forEach(element => {
    db.collection('test').update(
        { keyword: element },
        { keyword: element,
          search_num: 1}, 
        {upsert: true }
     )     
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want that. It sent 3 common